# When I push new value into array, variable return an integer

Tags: javascript

I try to push a new value into my array. But when I execute my code an integer is show instead my new array.

```js
var foo = ["Hello"].push(" word");
console.log(foo)
```

Comment: The `.push()` function returns the updated length of the array, and that's of course a number.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `concat` in this context to achieve your goal.

```js
var foo = ["Hello"].concat(" word");
console.log(foo)
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are storing the value that push returns on the variable `foo`:

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and **returns the new length of the array**.

You can do it this way:

```js
var arr = ["hello"];
arr.push(" word");
console.log(arr);
```